# Find length of string in Javascript (no built-in methods) recursively

Tags: javascript, string, recursion

Here's a tough question which I'm unable to solve.

**Write a recursive function that accepts a string and returns its length. Do not use the .length property, loops, or any built-in methods in Javascript to find the solution.**

I'm quite close with this solution but I'm not able to find an alternative to the `.slice()` method. This function currently works but doesn't fit the question's parameters because if uses that method, and the `.length` property:

```
let lengthGetter = (str, def) => {
  let len = def || 0;
  if (str[0] === undefined) return len;
  return lengthGetter(str.slice(0, str.length - 1), len + 1);
};

console.log(lengthGetter("hello")) // 5
```

Even if it involves throwing away my current function, can anyone find a solution to this problem? Keep in mind you can't use any built-in methods or loops, which makes it quite challenging.

Comment: You can check for the presence of a character with simplly `str[n]`; if that's `undefined` it means you're beyond the end of the string (or before the start).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close to what you have written:

```
let lengthGetter = (str, pos = 0) => {
  if (str[pos] === undefined) return 0;
  return 1 + lengthGetter(str, pos + 1);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the easiest recursive one-liner you can make to get the length of the given string without using any built-in methods.

```js
const getLength = (str = "", length = 0) => str[length] ? getLength(str, length + 1) : length;
```

Sample:

```js
const getLength = (str = "", length = 0) => str[length] ? getLength(str, length + 1) : length;

console.log(getLength("hello"))
console.log(getLength("helloworld"))
```

Comment: Well, using the fact that strings are iterable, this might be even easier: `const len = ([s, ...ss]) => s == undefined ? 0 : 1 +  len (ss)`

Comment: That's more neat.

Answer (score 2):

This often comes as a surprise:

```js
''.length
//=> 6
```

If you need to count what humans would see then you can destructure the string as most (but not all) characters would be preserved as such:

```js
[...''].length
//=> 3
```

So we can have:

```js
const Nil = Symbol();
const len = ([x = Nil, ...xs]) => x === Nil ? 0 : 1 + len(xs);

len('foo');
//=> 3
len('');
//=> 3
```